# HTTP GET request with parameters Node.js

Tags: node.js, api, http, get, request

I need to use linkBunch's [API](http://skmzq.qiniucdn.com/data/20080716092626/index.html) in my code and i don't have any experience in HTTP GET request with parameters, can anyone help me to write the HTTP request for this API with the parameters? thanks.

Comment: Why don't you edit your question and describe exactly which parameters you want to pass with the API call.  If you improve your question by being a lot more specific about what you want, you are a lot more likely to get the exact answer you want.  Trying to answer without that information would require a full tutorial on all the possible things you can pass and is just not likely to happen.  If you ask a really good question here that succinctly describes what you want, then you are very likely to get the exact answer you want.

Comment: if you open the link mentioned in the post you'll know exactly what i want.
http://skmzq.qiniucdn.com/data/20080716092626/index.html

Comment: The policy here on stack overflow is that ALL information required in order to fully understand the question should be directly in the question.  External links are OK for supplemental information, but not for required information.  That is because external links have a habit of changing or breaking with time and stack overflow is trying to create a lasting Q&A repository that will still be useful 10-15 years in the future.  It should be very little work for you to just show exactly what you want to do in the question.  That's how this place works.  There's an edit link that makes it easy.

Comment: okay understandable

Comment: Why have you not yet edited your question to show us what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: i've got my answer

Comment: Please learn how this community works and try to use it the way it works best for everyone.  If one of the answers provided below answered your question, then please click the green checkmark next to that answer to indicate you have an answer.  If not and you discovered the answer on your own, you can file your own answer to the question.  And, to make your question more useful for those that follow in this community, it would still be helpful if you would edit your question to show more detail about what you were actually trying to accomplish.  That would probably take about 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass the parameters right there in the url as with any get request. So in your case you need to add

```
?links=http://link1%0D%0Ahttp://link2%0D%0Ahttp://link3%0D%0A&bunch=Bunch&mode=api
```

to the linkbunch url specified in the link you supplied. 
That should do it.

Comment: i think this should work but instead, it printed undefined i think because of the captcha!

i tried to copy paste the link in my browser and i end up with a captcha

Comment: Ah ok, think I know what's going on here. If you read this /help.php (SO will not me post that complete linkbunch link - for the same reason as the following, I reckon...) you will see that the API has been deprecated. So unfortunately you will have to find another way to do what you need...

Comment: that's so disappointing. linkbunch is allowing you to put multiple links in one URL when you click on this URL it'll open a page containing the other links
did you know something similar?

Comment: I don't unfortunately and have been unable to locate anything like it. I guess it wouldn't be really hard to build and it's a nice idea...

Answer (score 0):

The API you are looking for has been deprecated unfortunately.  The logic to do what you are asking is pretty straight forward.  I've implemented it using express in glitch.  You can take a look at the code here https://glitch.com/edit/#!/hypnotic-sink?path=server.js:9:28  but basically it is just sending the `window.open` html back for every link you send in.

I've set it up for comma separated values so a valid example would be: https://hypnotic-sink.glitch.me/?links=https://www.google.com,http://www.bing.com

That link will open two tabs one with google in and one with bing in.

Comment: yea I know request library but where to pass the parameters mentioned in linkbunch's API? sorry if my question sounds stupid

Comment: I think it's gone.. As of December 1, 2013, the HTTP API is no longer available. Please stay tuned for further announcements. We regret the inconvenience caused.

Comment: do you know any similar service? to shorten multiple URLs into one link?
I'm afraid that bridgeurl's API is also gone!

Comment: I quickly made an api in glitch.  Hopefully you can copy it and alter it to suit exactly what you want, but it works OK how it is already

Comment: that's great but not exactly what I want. I want a shorten url, also this example isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

```
const request = require('request');

// Add all the links here
const links = [
    'http://link1.com',
    'http://link2.com',
    'http://link3.com'
];

const linkBunchURL = ''; // Add linkbunch URL here (http://linkbun...), as it cannot be posted within the answer
const mode = 'api';
const bunch = 'Bunch';
const linksParam = links.map(encodeURIComponent).join('%0D%0A');

request(`${linkBunchURL}?bunch=${bunch}&mode=${mode}&links=${linksParam}`, function (error, response, body) {
    console.log(response);
});
```